# CTF RSA Problem

Tags: encryption

I am doing a CTF and I came across a challenge I do not know how to solve. We are given a key generator and asked to find a way to factor the keys $N = pq$ it generates. The intended way is to disassemble the executable and see what it is doing. I haven't gotten far with that method given I can't read assembly. However, I did find an RSA public key and a few magic numbers hard-coded into the executable. The magic numbers do not divide the public key. It seems to be using a 1024-bit key to generate a 2048-bit key, but I don't know how.

I also noticed some patterns in the keys it generates. It seems one factor is always one more than double a prime $p=2r+1$. We also have $p,r \equiv 3 \mod 4$ while $N,q \equiv 1 \mod 4$. However, $p$ and $q$ are too far apart for factoring $N$ into a difference of two squares to be reliable. From here, I get stuck. It seems $q-1$ does not factor smoothly, so Pollard's $p-1$ is a bust. I was looking for relations with $p$ given its property, but I couldn't find anything.

Note that these may be two different vulnerabilities. The question hints there is one explicit backdoor coded in and one more "subtle" weakness.

Any advice, hints, or pointers would be appreciated.

EDIT: I should also note that $e=2^{16}+1$ and $d$ is large, as expected.

Comment: The only way to interpret $p,r \equiv 3 \mod 4 $ and $N,q \equiv 1 \mod 4$ that is consistent with $N=pq$, $p=2r+1$, $r$ prime, $p>5$ is $pr\equiv3\pmod4$ and $Nq\equiv1\pmod4$, thus $p\equiv q\equiv1\pmod4$. Please clarify! The only likely way to solve the CTF without understanding the disassembly is to identify the subtle weakness, but the observations made do not amount to an exploitable weakness. Thus I'm pessimistic that we can guess how to solve the CTF from what's in the question. If the CTF is public, please link to it. Are you allowed to ask? What about learning to read assembly?

Comment: https://beginners.re/ is a free book on learning to read assembly (and other reverse-engineering tasks).